# My First Grid Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I've follow this instruccion http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid
but my grid is not working. The DATA is only in my first page. And the  navigation bar doesn't work and there is a message (UNDEFINED) in the grid.. PLEASE HELP ME I Did all the instruccion
you can see a screenshot here: http://reyes.hostei.com/screenshot.jpg

And this is my code source.

```
...
<link href="logica/scripts/jquery.jqGrid-3.6.2/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css"     rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="logica/scripts/jquery.jqGrid-3.6.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 75%;
}
</style>

<!-- Of course we should load the jquery library -->
<script src="logica/scripts/jquery.jqGrid-3.5.3/js/jquery.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Idioma de la libreria.. Antes de incluir esta -->
<script src="logica/scripts/jquery.jqGrid-3.5.3/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"   type="text/x-javascript"></script>
<!-- and at end the jqGrid Java Script file -->
<script src="logica/scripts/jquery.jqGrid-3.5.3/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="logica/scripts/jquery.jqGrid-3.5.3/js/jqModal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="logica/scripts/jquery.jqGrid-3.5.3/js/jqDnR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
  jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'server.php',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'invid', index:'invid', width:55}, 
      {name:'invdate', index:'invdate', width:90}, 
      {name:'amount', index:'amount', width:80, align:'right'}, 
      {name:'tax', index:'tax', width:80, align:'right'}, 
      {name:'total', index:'total', width:80, align:'right'}, 
      {name:'note', index:'note', width:150, sortable:false} 
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:7,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: 'invid',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'EXAMPLE DON`T WORK'
  }); 
}); 
</script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="list"></table> 
<div id="pager"></div> 
...
```

I NEED YOUR HELP!!!!!

Comment: Install FireBug and check requests that jqGrid send, as well as JavaScript errors (you can do this in Errors Console in FireFox, too).

Answer (score 1):

If your path naming can be relied on, you seems to be using css for jqGrid 3.6.2 but the js is for jqGrid 3.5.3

And any specific reason to use `text/x-javascript` instead of `text/javascript` in that `grid.locale-en.js` line?

About the paging not working.., show us your server side paging code.., you need to page the data on the server side (based on the page number passed by jqGrid).